# Vertically aligning text to graphics based bullets

Tags: css, stylesheet

See the bullets on this blog post:
http://www.nielsbrinch.com/managing-expectation-management/

I have had to change to text characteristics in order to align the text to the graphics based bullets. I would like to set the same line-height (25) as the rest of the text, but had to set it to 15 in order for the alignment to the orange bullet to be correct.

Here are the combined styles for the bullets.

```
.post ul li {
    background: url(images/yellow-bullet.png) no-repeat 0px 4px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    line-height: 15px;
    font-size: 11pt;
    padding-top: -12px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Question: How do I ensure to keep the text correctly aligned with the bullets, while preserving full control of the text characteristics?

(I want to do this only by changing the styles, please do not suggest that I change the html structure, such as including a div in the li tag)

Comment: post a jsfiddle and we can help you debug.

Comment: I've never used that before - but it seems to work:
http://jsfiddle.net/SbedL/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list-style-image: url(images/yellow-bullet.png);
```

instead of

```
background: url(images/yellow-bullet.png) no-repeat 0px 4px;
```

should do the trick?

Comment: Weird. What does mean "100% aligned"? Can you post an image of what do you want? By the way, negative padding are not allowed ;)

Comment: The text is currently aligned one or two pixels above the bullet.

Comment: Yep, it's because your image is smaller than text. As you cannot specify vertical-align of the bullet you could solve that adding transparent space at the bottom of the image.

Comment: Any other suggestions on what I can do purely with CSS? No amount of margin, padding or positioning can remedy the problem?

Comment: I don't believe there's a means to control the bullet positioning independently.  The HTML based bullets are center aligned based on line-height (I would suppose).  The graphical ones... it seems like you are on your own to position them.  MadTheCat's suggestion on adding transparent space seems like the appropriate one.